# Redirecionamento com .htaccess

Tags: apache, htaccess, redirecionamento, mod-rewrite

Estou usando a seguinte regra de mod-rewrite

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?lang=$1&page=$2 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Mas agora preciso redirecionar uma página antiga para a nova. Então fiz o seguinte:

```
Redirect 301 /port/reestruturacao-financeira http://website.com/port/reestruturacao-corporativa/
```

Onde a segunda é a página nova. Mas o browser retornou isso:

http://website.com/port/reestruturacao-corporativa//?lang=port&page=reestruturacao-financeira

Comment: Tenta assim:

Redirect 301 /pagina_antiga.php http://www.example.com/nova_pagina.php

Comment: Coloca o .htaccess todo por favor

Comment: @tkmattos resposta aqui: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37049524/3691686